# Are there any superheroes in the Spider-Verse that are not Spider-Beings?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse, spider-man-across-the-spider-verse

Here, I am referring to the animated Spider-Man films *Into the Spider-Verse* and *Across the Spider-Verse*.

We have seen (or seen refernced) many a Spider-Man variant, many villains, and some anti-heroes (Venom).

Are there supposed to be literally no superheroes in any of the universes who are not Spider-Beings?

Comment: Sony Pictures is likely very limited in which other heroes they can mention in their films, since I believe they only own the movie rights to Spider-Man-related characters. The movie rights to the Avengers, X-Men, Fantastic Four, Daredevil, Punisher, etc. are all owned by Marvel Studios, so Sony would need to work out a deal with them to use any of those characters, and my impression is that Kevin Feige doesn't want to share. (He seemingly doesn't even want them to use Spider-Man in their live-action films.)

Comment: I believe Sony could use Silver Sable, a Black Widow-esque mercenary who repeatedly fought alongside Spider-Man and only takes jobs where she's up against criminals. There are also a few characters -- such as the Prowler, Rocket Racer, and the Steel Spider -- who initially started out as small-time crooks, but soon reformed and became heroes going forward. You also have characters who've gone back & forth, like the Sandman, the Black Cat, and Morbius.

Answer (score 8):

Doctor Strange gets a mention in the new *Across the Spider-verse* film.

> *"Now, don't even get me started on Dr. Strange, the little nerd back on Earth 1999999"*

I'm pretty sure he meets the definition of "superhero".

Comment: Good find......

Comment: @ThePopMachine - [Those are the only finds I know](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)

Comment: I guess the follow up is:   Did they make specific arrangements with Disney?  And why even bother with the one?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - There are a bunch of disney-copyrighted things in the film, including mention of Doctor Strange, depiction of the multi-verse, etc. I'm guessing these were all run by Disney's creatives and lawyers.

Comment: @Valorum - Is the concept of a multiverse strictly copyrighted by Disney? It's not something I'd strictly associate with the Avengers, X-Men, FF, etc.

Comment: @LogicDictates - No, but the very specific graphic of the multiverse as a branch of a glowing line thing is copyrightable; https://thedirect.com/article/spider-verse-2-tom-hiddleston-loki-easter-egg

Comment: @Valorum - Interesting that they showed that depiction of the Sacred Timeline in the _Across the Spider-Verse_. _Spider-Man: No Way Home_ already established that Sony's live-actions films take place within the same multiverse as the MCU films. This is now indicating that Sony's animated Spidey films take place in that multiverse, too, in which case there are _plenty_ of non-Spidey-related heroes in said multiverse.

Comment: The big, remaining question is whether the multiverse in these Disney and Sony films is the same as the one in Marvel comics. (The reference to Earth-1999999 perhaps implies that it is, since that term originated in the Official Handbooks for the Marvel comics, as a designation for the MCU.) And if it is, then essentially every Marvel hero ever is part of the same multiverse as the Spider-Verse films; it's just that Sony doesn't have the rights to use most of those characters without approval from Disney.

Comment: @LogicDictates - The makers of the films have been pretty clear that these nods (as well as a bunch of other pop-culture references) as there for fun and don't mean that the film is connected to the MCU directly

Comment: @Valorum - It seems odd that they'd clearly establish that the live-action films take place in the same multiverse, but draw a line at the animated films being in that multiverse as well.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Ah, but are those the same live-action Spider-men, or simply variants that happen to look a lot like them

Comment: @Valorum - I'm not sure the term 'variant' would apply if they don't exist in the same multiverse. But we may be entering into "distinction without a difference" territory now.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question a while back. The short answer is: yes, there are other superheroes in the "Spider-Verse".

To understand why the answer is a pretty simple yes, we need to understand that when it comes to marvel, pretty much all marvel media is part of the marvel multiverse. When it comes to the multiverse, due to the MCU and the Spider-Verse movies, it's getting a little bit wonkie. This is because the MCU declared itself Universe 616 even though the comic main universe already is Universe 616, and the universe Miles comes from in the Spider-Verse movies is also considered Universe 1610, which in the comics is the Ultimate universe (where Miles also first appeared in the comics after it's Peter died due to being shot by the punisher and right after having to fight a couple of villains who escaped from Prison, including Norman Osborn in his goblin form trying to kill him and his family). Funny enough, the Spider-Verse movies even "made fun" of the fact the MCU declares itself as 616 when Miguel O'Hara (Spider-Man 2099) said

> Now, don't even get me started on Dr. Strange and the little nerd back
> on Earth 1999999

referencing the movie Spider-Man No Way Home and it's Multiverse event.

So not only is it theoretically true that this movie is part of the Marvel Multiverse, the movie even references the multiverse (this is not the only occasion. The "Canon Events" scene utilizes scenes from Spider-Man (2002), The Amazing Spider-Man and from the comics to show "Canon Events"). So yeah, they reference at least 2 universes in which other heroes exist. Comic 616 and the MCU 199999.